# What is preferable choice for integration: Salesforce to Salesforce or MiddleWare tool?

Tags: integration, salesforce2salesforce, externalobjects

If there are two companies which use the same Order data and the data is created in company A and then the Order data should be sent to company B, should Salesforce to Salesforce integration be used or middle ware tool to pull orders from Company A and push them into Company B?

Comment: Can I recommend changing the title to explicitly mention Order, like "How can I sync Orders between Salesforce orgs?" since this is fundamentally what you're asking and answering here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Spring '21 release, there is a limited [list of Standard Salesforce objects which are supported by the Salesforce to Salesforce feature](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.business_network_publish_objects.htm&type=5)

1. Account
2. Attachment (unencrypted)
3. Case
4. Case Comment
5. Contact
6. Lead
7. Opportunity
8. Opportunity Product
9. Product
10. Task
11. Custom Object

and Order is not present in the list, so to send Orders from one org to another, another solution should be used like External Data Source: Cross Org Adapter or a MiddleWare application to pull Order records from Company A and push them into Company B.

Comment: I think it worthwhile stating that this answer is valid as of Spring '21 release...?

Comment: Ok, updated my answer